# Convert SQL Server spatial table with unknown coordinate reference system to GeoJSON with ogr2ogr

Tags: coordinate-system, geojson, sql-server, ogr2ogr

I have a table in SQL Server with an `STSrid` of `0`. I would like to convert this table to GeoJSON using `ogr2ogr`. The problem is, despite converting to `EPSG:4326`, the resulting coordinates are not valid (verified using GeoJSONLint). The GeoJSON file's `crs` key lists the coordinate reference system as the desired `CRS84`, but the feature coordinates are far too large.

A sample feature appears as such:

```
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "TR": "00028" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 447366.18450000137, -920054.45910000056 ] } }
```

The output coordinates as seen above are identical to the input:

```
select TR, Shape.STX, Shape.STY from [table] where TR = '00028'
```

results in:

```
00028   447366.184500001    -920054.459100001
```

I'm entering the following `ogr2ogr` command:

```
ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" "sqlexport.json" "MSSQL:server=[server];database=[db];trusted_connection=yes;" -sql "select TR, Shape from [table]" -a_srs "EPSG:4326"
```

Edit: 
Despite SQL Server listing the `STSrid` as `0`, ArcGIS reads it as `GCS_North_American_1983`:

```
Custom
Projection: Two_Point_Equidistant
False_Easting: 0.0
False_Northing: 0.0
Latitude_Of_1st_Point: 49.0
Latitude_Of_2nd_Point: 49.0
Longitude_Of_1st_Point: -110.0
Longitude_Of_2nd_Point: -77.0
Linear Unit: Meter (1.0)

Geographic Coordinate System: GCS_North_American_1983
Angular Unit: Degree (0.0174532925199433)
Prime Meridian: Greenwich (0.0)
Datum: D_North_American_1983
  Spheroid: GRS_1980
    Semimajor Axis: 6378137.0
    Semiminor Axis: 6356752.314140356
    Inverse Flattening: 298.257222101
```

Despite this, if I change the `ogr2ogr` command to the following:

```
ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" "sqlexport.json" "MSSQL:server=[server];database=[db];trusted_connection=yes;" -sql "select TR, Shape from [table]" -s_srs "EPSG:4140" -t_srs "EPSG:4326"
```

The coordinates still remain unchanged.

Comment: how do the coordinates look in SQL server when you use table.geometry.STX / .STY?

Comment: @mapBaker: see above edit. The input coordinates are identical to the GeoJSON output

Comment: those coordinates don't look like WGS 84 / 4326... they look to be in UTM or something...

Comment: What location does the data represent? City, county/province/state, address? With that information someone may be able to identify the coordinate reference system.

Comment: @mkennedy: see update. According to ArcGIS, the geographic coordinate system is GCS_North_American_1983.

Comment: No, ArcGIS recognizes it as a custom projected coordinate reference system using the two point equidistant projection, and based on NAD83. On your 2nd ogr2ogr command EPSG:4140 is deprecated (no longer in use), NAD83 (CSRS98). The data is not in a geographic coordinate system. What happens if you use -t_srs 4326, but omit both -s_srs and -a_srs?

Comment: I tried omitting both -s_srs and -a_srs previously. I receive the error: Can't transform coordinates, source layer has no coordinate system.  Use -s_srs to set one. Based on the deprecated reference code you mentioned, I tried it with what I believe is the up-to-date ID for NAD 1983: EPSG:4269. Once again, the coordinates were left unchanged. Are the coordinates not supposed to change or something? It seems as if no matter what I do, they remain the same as the original coordinates.

Comment: Ogr2ogr need -s_srs and -t_srs as a pair. But EPSG:4269 must still be wrong http://epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4269. Based on the coordinate values your data is in some projected system. For proofing that coordinates can change try -s_srs epsg:3857 -t_srs epsg:4326. Your projection is close to this http://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/54031/prettywkt/ and then you can edit the proj4 string and give that as s_srs for GDAL http://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/54031/proj4/

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on the instructions you gave. I tried -s_srs epsg:3857 -t_srs epsg:4326, which generated the following coordinate pair: [ 4.018758811345848, -8.236474462418984 ] . This projects in GeoJSONLint west of Africa in the Atlantic Ocean. The correct coordinate pair should be  [ -88.129664, 41.736341 ] , a location in Naperville, IL.

Comment: I'm pretty certain this is entirely hopeless. I just tried to use the brute force method for determining the coordinate system made possible here - http://websites.greeninfo.org/greeninfo/labs/projectionuesser/live/, and none landed in Naperville, IL. The closest projection was Canada Atlas Lambert, landing in Peoria, IL. I'm not sure what genius decided it would be a good idea to set everything into a custom projection, but it has led to a lot of frustration on my end.

Comment: I gave the epsg:3857 example for showing you that ogr2ogr can do conversion. All you need to do is to use correct -s_srs and I am sure you can solve it by studying how to feed the two point equidistant parameters from the ArcGIS report into +proj4 string that you feed as -s_srs for ogr2ogr. Lat1 lon1 lat2 lon2 are the parameters you must adjust.

Comment: Ok, so I converted it to a shapefile, and then ran the following command on the output .prj file: gdalsrsinfo [table].prj. This generated the following: PROJ.4 : '+proj=tpeqd +lat_1=49 +lon_1=-110 +lat_2=49 +lon_2=-77 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs '. How can I use this PROJ.4 string in an ogr2ogr conversion?

Comment: Boom! It worked! I placed the PROJ.4 string in front of -s_srs. Thank you @user30184! If you want to provide your suggestion as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: Write what you did as an answer yourself. You discovered to use gdalsrsinfo for getting a good proj4 string but I was just encouraging you to go on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to determine the correct coordinate system for the input SQL Server data, I exported the data as a shapefile, and ran the following command on the `prj` file:

```
gdalsrsinfo [table].prj
```

This generated the following PROJ.4 string:

```
+proj=tpeqd +lat_1=49 +lon_1=-110 +lat_2=49 +lon_2=-77 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs
```

I then placed the PROJ.4 string in front of the `-s_srs` flag in the `ogr2ogr` command like so:

```
ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" "sqlexport.json" "MSSQL:server=[server];database[db];trusted_connection=yes;" -sql "select TR, Shape from [table]" -s_srs "+proj=tpeqd +lat_1=49 +lon_1=-110 +lat_2=49 +lon_2=-77 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs" -t_srs "EPSG:4326"
```